# how to get data object when graphQl sends error object along with data object as something is not found in query

Tags: angular, graphql, frontend

[image: i am getting data along with error object in graph Ql query. I just need data object as it contains some data i require. I am unable to get data object in subscribe response.]

here i am hitting query to get response i just need to console data object.

```js
 this.query = this.customerService.getCardHolder(id);
    this.query.valueChanges.subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log("detail response",response.errors);
        //it does not come here.
      }, (error) =>{
      //it comes here but did not find data object. just finding error object.
        console.log("detail error", error.graphQLErrors[0]);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

just add  `queryOpts.errorPolicy = 'ignore';`
i-e

```js
 const queryOpts = { query } as any;
    queryOpts.fetchPolicy = 'network-only';
    queryOpts.errorPolicy = 'ignore';
    if (variables) {
      queryOpts.variables = variables;
      
    }
    return this.apollo.watchQuery(queryOpts);
```